# Iterating over grouped data and applying function pairwise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, group-by

I have a data frame which I want to group and apply a function over the grouped data frames (by Iteration).

For example :

A df (A,B,C-are the column names) and a function f that gets 2 data frames  as input and returns a number:

```
df:
A B C
a d 1
a e 2
a f 3
b d 4
b f 3
b r 8
c t 9
c e 2
c p 5
```

function:

```
def chi_dist(df1,df2):
    result = pd.merge(df1,df2, how="left", on=['B'])
    result['sub']=(result['B_x']-result['B_y'])**2
    return (result['sub'].sum(min_count=1))
```

I want to group the df by column A

```
 grouped=df.groupby('A')
```

and apply the function on each one of the pairs of the group with name 'a' and the other 'b' and 'c' (this is what I tried)

```
for name, group in grouped:
    print(name)
    print(f(group,group+1))
```

desired output :

```
a
9
b
0
c
0
```

Comment: You function doesn't work. When you merge on 'B' you don't get B_x and B_y.

Comment: IIUC: You can get the combinations with `q = itertools.combinations(grouped,2)`; then iterate over them with `for (name1,group1),(name2,group2) in q:...`

Comment: I've tried to loop this way by it doesn't give me all the combination just the (i,i+i)  so the last group of the data frame doesnt appear